# Database access using parametrized and prepared statements

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Simple question. I am using Java and MySQL database. I want to write database access methods what would use PreparedStatement method and would be parametrized, such as:

```
 public DBResult selectQueryWithParameters(String SQL, Object... params)
```

I know that you can do this for select queries, but what about DROP, CREATE and ALTER queries what are using execute(SQL) method. Likewise you may execute UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE queries what are using executeUpdate(SQL) method. Can I write parametrized methods for these queries?
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Connection's prepareStatement method to prepare a statement.  Then you can use setInt, setString, setXX methods to set the parameters.  This works for SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE.

Why would you want a PreparedStatement for DROP, CREATE, ALTER?
CREATE TABLE stuff ( message VARCHAR(?) ) ;

It does not make much sense to me.

Comment: This is because those activities such as DROP or ALTER might be done dynamically when the table you drop is passed as parameter. Due to security is better to use parameterized method to do that. PreparedStatement just improves the performance. So, what about my question? Can I make those methods parametrized?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can use PreparedStatements for DROPs, CREATEs, and ALTERs.  However you can not actually have parameters in these statements.  I have not verified this comment.  So you can check it for yourself.  Having said that, it is in my opinion a bad practice.  DROP, CREATE, and ALTER should be rare events and not part of your application.